# Would this line of code really work for detecting HTML5 support?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm working on an existing application and came across the following line of code:

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

               DoSomething();

            }
```

It doesn't appear to work, especially with IE. Is there a better way to check for HTML5 support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Check for HTML5 support" is an overly ambitious goal.  Each user agent has different levels of supporting different features of HTML, so it's not a simple all-encompassing "Yes, this supports HTML5."

In fact, the code you quote seems to do well - it tests for the features it needs (apparently for reading blobs from the operating system), not for the whole generic concept.

The standard is to do something like what you quote, and only check for the features you want.  If that statement is returning a false negative, you may want to look into support libraries that handle feature detection, like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 is just a buzzword.  Browsers support a varying matrix of things that we would classify as "HTML5".  The code you have is doing "feature detection" for whether the browser supports the file & blob APIs.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot detect full HTML5 support in general there is a javascript library called [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/), which allows you to detect HTML5 and CSS3 support by features.